# Busca em Largura - error: 'str_no' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, syntax-error

Tenho o seguinte código em `C`, para um busca em largura:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

//Variáveis globais
int id = 0;
int proximo = 0;

//Função de Busca em Largura
int buscaLargura(int *grafo, int alvo, int inicio, int tamanho)
{
    struct str_no fila[tamanho];
    int indice = 0;
    int achou = 0;

    //Procura nó inicial
    while(achou == 0)
    {
        if(grafo->id == inicio)
        {
            achou = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            grafo = grafo->proximo;
        }
    }
    achou = 0;
}

//Procura o nó alvo
fila[indice] = grafo;
indice++;
while(indice > 0 && achou == 0)
{
    if(grafo->id == alvo)
    {
        achou = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        while(grafo->proximo != NULL)
        {
            grafo = grafo->proximo;
            fila[indice] = grafo;
            indice++;
        }
        //Desenfileira
        grafo = pilha[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < indice; i++)
        {
            pilha[i-1] = pilha[i];
        }
        indice--;
    }
    return(grafo);
}
```

---

Sempre que tento executar, o compilador "CodeBlocks" retorna o seguinte **ERRO**:

> ||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
>   In function 'buscaLargura':| |17|error: array type has incomplete
>   element type| |24|error: request for member 'id' in something not a
>   structure or union| |30|error: request for member 'proximo' in
>   something not a structure or union| |error: 'indice' undeclared here
>   (not in a function)| |37|warning: data definition has no type or
>   storage class| |37|error: 'grafo' undeclared here (not in a function)|
>   |38|error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before
>   '++' token| |39|error: expected identifier or '(' before 'while'|
>   ||=== Build failed: 7 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0
>   second(s)) ===|

Answer (score 0):

Há vários erros no seu programa:

**|17|error: array type has incomplete element type|**

O erro está na linha:

```
struct str_no fila[tamanho];
```

O primeiro erro é que você não declarou o tipo "struct str_no" e já está tentando criar uma variável deste tipo. Outro erro é que você não pode declarar um array **estático** usando um tamanho **dinâmico**. Ou você define um tamanho fixo:

```
struct str_no fila[10];
```

Ou você deverá alocar o array dinamicamente:

```
struct str_no *fila = malloc(sizeof(*fila) * tamanho);
```

**|24|error: request for member 'id' in something not a structure or union|:**
**|30|error: request for member 'proximo' in something not a structure or union|**

A variável **grafo** é um ponteiro para **int**, e não uma estrutura. Portanto, não faz sentido acessar membros chamados **id** e **proximo**, que não existem: **grafo->id**.

Nem vou falar dos demais erros. Claramente você precisa estudar a sintaxe da linguagem C.

Comment: Muito obrigado, estou fazendo isso, estudando incansavelmente essa linguagem de programação, suas dicas e explicações me serviram muito

Comment: Sobre array estático com valor dinâmico, na verdade na verdade, você pode. Talvez não seja C89, mas C99 já é. E é [considerado alocação estática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/215832/64969)

Answer (score 0):

O primeiro ponto aqui é: o que é uma `struct str_no`? No momento atual, o compilador não faz ideia do que seja. Como você está tentando criar um vetor com `tamanho` elementos, o compilador vai pegar um valor indeterminado e multiplicar pela parâmetro `tamanho` para alocar a memória necessária para o vetor existir... e, bem, dá erro...

Outro ponto é que `grafo` é um ponteiro para inteiro, não para `struct str_no`, então ele não tem atributos para você referir com o operador seta `->`. Portanto, `grafo->id` não é exequível.

Finalmente, tem o problema do fim prematuro da função. Creio que toda essa parte desde o `fila[indice] = grafo;` deveria ser a continuação da função. Mas, tem um fecha chaves indicando que terminou um bloco logo antes. Como o único bloco aberto é o da função `buscaLargura`, o fecha chaves termina essa função. Tudo que se encontra depois disso está no contexto global. E pelo que me lembre no contexto global só se pode ter declarações, seja de variáveis, tipos ou funções, nada de comandos. Os erros a partir da linha 37 podem ser interpretados como erros colaterais ao fechamento prematuro da função.

Mesmo colocando o bloco restante de código solto dentro da função, ainda há o caso de que dentro do `for` você usa uma variável não declarada chamada `pilha`. Creio que você queria usar a `fila` aqui, correto?

---

Certo, já falamos muito em erros, e que tal falar em como corrigir?

O primeiro passo, é declarar a estrutura *antes* da criação da função `buscaLargura`. Isso pode ser feito copiando e colando o `struct str_no { ... }` para o começo do arquivo ou, caso esteja separando em múltiplos arquivos fonte, importando o `.h` necessário.

A segunda correção é corrigir o tipo de `int *grafo` para `struct str_no *grafo` nos parâmetros da função `buscaLargura`.

O terceiro ponto é colocar o trecho de código solto dentro da função. Aproveitando também o terceiro ponto, retirar menção à variável `pilha`; deveria ser `fila` no lugar.