# Alocar memória em C para vetor de estrutura

Tags: c, array, struct, memória

Qual é a forma certa de alocar memória para um vetor de estruturas?

```
struct CARRO{
    int id;
    char fabricante[MAX];
    char modelo[MAX];
    int ano;
    char cor[MAX];
    int preco;
};

int main(){

    int qtd, i;
    scanf("%d", &qtd);

    struct CARRO *carros[qtd];

    *carros[qtd] = (struct CARRO *) malloc(qtd * sizeof(struct CARRO));

}
```

Comment: Amigo, você pode dar uma olhada [neste link](https://www.ime.usp.br/~mms/mac1222s2014/9%20-%20structs%20e%20ponteiros.pdf) que tem um caso semelhante ao que você precisa (no código nas páginas 4 e 5, ele faz uma alocação bem parecida com o que você deseja). Espero que ajude!

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

Na verdade é bem simples. Estou entendendo que quer fazer uma alocação dinâmica. Então não precisa nada de `[qtd]`. Ou faz de um jeito ou faz de outro.

Tem maneiras melhores de fazer isto, mas vai aprendendo uma coisa de cada vez.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 30

struct CARRO{
    int id;
    char fabricante[MAX];
    char modelo[MAX];
    int ano;
    char cor[MAX];
    int preco;
};

int main() {
    int qtd;
    scanf("%d", &qtd);
    struct CARRO *carros = malloc(qtd * sizeof(struct CARRO));
    free(carros); //só para usar a variável, neste caso não precisa
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/Bzg9a0). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hbxjnxap-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/Array.c).

Note que não usei *cast* porque ele pode esconder um erro de programação e atribui junto da declaração que é o mais intuitivo e moderno.

Se fosse estática seria só:

```
int qtd;
scanf("%d", &qtd);
struct CARRO carros[qtd];
```

A alocação estática sempre é preferida quando é possível.

Na verdade neste caso específico o termo usado é alocação automática, porque ela é feito no *stack* ou registrador (por ser um vetor complexo não cabe no registrador, mas um simples ou um tipo escalar poderia ser). A alocação estática pode ocorrer no *heap* também, desde que faça parte de um estrutura alocada dinamicamente. É o caso do `char fabricante[MAX];` por exemplo, que é alocada dentro de `CARRO` de forma *inline*, mas só existirá quando da alocação dinâmica no [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

Comment: Só faltou o `return 0;` na `main` ;-)

Comment: Não é necessário fazer isto.

Comment: Brigadão @bigown :D

Answer (score 2):

Você deve definir o ponteiro `carros` como sendo apenas `struct CARRO *carros`. Da forma como você escreveu, você estava definindo `carros` como sendo um vetor de ponteiros de estruturas, ao invés de simplesmente um vetor de estruturas.

Além disso, na hora de atribuir um valor ao ponteiro, você deve utilizar apenas o nome dele, sem o asterisco. Caso contrário, você estará se referindo não ao ponteiro, mas ao espaço de memória apontado por ele (no caso, a estrutura `CARROS`).

O código deve então ficar assim:

```
int main() {

    int qtd;
    struct CARRO *carros;

    scanf("%d", &qtd);

    carros = (struct CARRO *) malloc(qtd * sizeof(struct CARRO));

}
```

Comment: Fazer o *cast* é prejudicial ao código e atribuir separado da declaração é uma técnica do século passado.

Comment: @bigown século passado ok, mas qual a boa prática para falar que o _cast_ sobre `malloc` é prejudicial? Que eu me lembre, o _cast_ livre de `void*` era do C++, não algo que deveria ser usado no C

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado em C++ não é pra usar `malloc()` se for usado ele deve ter *cast*, em C não deve ter *cast* porque é outra linguagem com semântica diferente. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123208/101

Comment: @bigown ok, fiz uma bagunça com C é C++ :P, troquei foi tudo. E sim, C++ vida longa ao `new`

Answer (score 2):

Uma alternativa para alocação dinâmica de memória seria através da função `calloc()`, que além de alocar memória da mesma forma que o `malloc()`, é capaz de inicializar a memória alocada com 'zeros':

```
void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);
```

Possui um protótipo mais 'intuitivo' pois recebe dois argumentos: A quantidade de elementos (`nmemb`) e o tamanho de cada um desses elementos (`size`).

Segue um exemplo de como solucionar o seu problema:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define MAX         (100)
#define QTD_CARROS  (5)


struct CARRO {
    int id;
    char fabricante[MAX];
    char modelo[MAX];
    int ano;
    char cor[MAX];
    int preco;
};

typedef struct CARRO carro_t;


void carro_preencher( carro_t * c, int id, char * fab, char * mod, int ano, char * cor, int preco )
{
    c->id = id;
    strncpy( c->fabricante, fab, MAX );
    strncpy( c->modelo, mod, MAX );
    c->ano = ano;
    strncpy( c->cor, cor, MAX );
    c->preco = preco;
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    /* Cria array de carros */
    carro_t * carros = calloc( QTD_CARROS, sizeof(carro_t) );

    /* Preenche os dados de cada Carro na array */
    carro_preencher( &carros[0], 1000, "Volkswagen", "Kombi", 1980, "Branco", 1000 );
    carro_preencher( &carros[1], 2000, "Chevrolet", "Camaro", 2017, "Amarelo", 80000 );
    carro_preencher( &carros[2], 3000,"Fiat",  "Uno", 2005, "Cinza", 5000 );
    carro_preencher( &carros[3], 4000,"Ford", "Fiesta", 2001, "Vermelho", 10500 );
    carro_preencher( &carros[4], 5000,"Toyota", "Corolla", 2017, "Prata", 70000 );

    /* Libera array de carros */
    free(carros);

    return 0;
}
```

Uma segunda alternativa, seria fazer a alocação por meio de um par de funções capazes de construir/destruir um único `Carro`.

Essas funções seriam chamadas para cada elemento da array, de forma indenpendente, no momento da construção e da destruição de cada `Carro`.

Segue um outro exemplo mais elaborado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define QTD_CARROS  (5)


struct CARRO {
    int id;
    char * fabricante;
    char * modelo;
    int ano;
    char * cor;
    int preco;
};


typedef struct CARRO carro_t;


carro_t * carro_construir(  int id, char * fab, char * mod, int ano, char * cor, int preco )
{
    carro_t * c = calloc( 1, sizeof(carro_t) );

    c->id = id;
    c->fabricante = strdup(fab);
    c->modelo = strdup(mod);
    c->ano = ano;
    c->cor = strdup(cor);
    c->preco = preco;

    return c;
}


void carro_destruir( carro_t * c )
{
    free(c->fabricante);
    free(c->modelo);
    free(c->cor);
    free(c);
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int i = 0;
    carro_t * carros[ QTD_CARROS ]; /* Array de carros */

    /* Constroi um Carro para cada elemento da array... */
    carros[0] = carro_construir( 1000, "Volkswagen", "Kombi", 1980, "Branco", 1000 );
    carros[1] = carro_construir( 2000, "Chevrolet", "Camaro", 2017, "Amarelo", 80000 );
    carros[2] = carro_construir( 3000, "Fiat",  "Uno", 2005, "Cinza", 5000 );
    carros[3] = carro_construir( 4000, "Ford", "Fiesta", 2001, "Vermelho", 10500 );
    carros[4] = carro_construir( 5000, "Toyota", "Corolla", 2017, "Prata", 70000 );

    /* Destroi cada Carro contido na array */
    for( i = 0; i < QTD_CARROS; i++ )
        carro_destruir( carros[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Lacobus, sua explicação e exemplos foram muito úteis. :D