# Dados não persistem no switch case

Tags: c, c++, switch

Escrever um programa que cadastre o nome, a altura, o peso, o cpf e sexo de algumas pessoas. Com os dados cadastrados, em seguida localizar uma pessoas através do seu CPF e imprimir o seu IMC.

Quando escolho a opção de Consulta os dados que foram inseridos antes não permanecem. Qual o motivo?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Cadastro{
    char nome[30];
    char condicao[30];
    char sexo;
    int CPF;
    float altura;
    float peso;
    float imc;
};
void Menu(){
    printf(" ====== Menu ====== \n");
    printf("1 - Cadastrar\n");
    printf("2 - Consultar \n");
    printf("3 - Sair\n");
    printf(" ================== \n");
}

main(){
    int opcao, contUser = 0;
    do{
        Menu();
        scanf("%i", &opcao);
        system("cls");
        if(opcao == 1){
        printf("Quantos cadastros deseja realizar? ");
        scanf("%i", &contUser);
        system("cls");
        fflush(stdin);
        }
        Cadastro user[contUser];

        system("cls");
        switch(opcao){
            case 1 :
                printf(" ==== Cadastro ==== \n");
                for(int i = 0; i<contUser; i++){

                    printf(" ====== %i/%i ======\n", i+1, contUser);
                    printf("Digite o nome: ");
                    scanf("%[^\n]", user[i].nome);
                    fflush(stdin);
                    printf("Digite sexo. \nf - feminino\nm - masculino: ");
                    scanf("%c", &user[i].sexo);
                    printf("Digite o CPF: ");
                    scanf("%i", &user[i].CPF);
                    printf("Digite a altura em metros(m): ");
                    scanf("%f", &user[i].altura);
                    printf("Digite o peso em quilos(kg): ");
                    scanf("%f", &user[i].peso);
                    user[i].imc = user[i].peso/(user[i].altura*user[i].altura);

                    /*if(user[i].sexo == 'f'){
                        if(user[i].imc < 19.1){
                            user[i].condicao = {"Peso Baixo"};

                        }
                    }*/
                    fflush(stdin);
                    system("cls");
                }
                system("cls");
                break;

            case 2 :
                char qualquer;
                if(contUser == 0){
                    printf("Nenhum usuario cadastrado. Pressione qualquer tecla para voltar para o menu.");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%c", &qualquer);
                    system("cls");
                }else{
                int consulta;
                    printf(" ==== Consulta ==== \n");
                    printf("Digite o CPF do cadastro: ");
                    scanf("%i", &consulta);

                    for(int i = 0; i<contUser; i++){
                        if(user[i].CPF == consulta){
                        printf("%f", user[i].imc);
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

            case 3 :
                printf("Obrigado!");
                break;
        }
    }while(opcao != 3);
}
```

Estou usando a seguinte entrada para testar:

```
1
1
1
Nome
m
1234
1.5
22.5
2
1234
3
```

> Por partes:
>
> ```
> 1
> 1
> ```
>
> Estou abrindo um único cadastro.
>
> ```
> 1
> Nome
> m
> 1234
> 1.5
> 22.5
> ```
>
> Estou selecionando a opção de cadastro, inserindo nome `Nome`, sexo
>   `m`, CPF `1234`, altura `1.5` e peso `22.5`.
>
> ```
> 2
> 1234
> ```
>
> Estou verificando o IMC gravado para a pessoa com CPF `1234`.
>
> ```
> 3
> ```

Estou encerrando o programa.

O resultado esperado é `10.0`, mas não estou obtendo esse valor.

Também fiz um teste deixando o case 2 apenas para exibir o primeiro CPF cadastrado.

```
case 2:
   printf("%i", user[0].CPF);
   break;
```

Sai um valor aleatório diferente do CPF que foi cadastrado.

Comment: Pode me ajudar? Quais foram os passos que você seguiu para simular o problema?

Comment: Na primeira execução eu escolho a opção 1 para cadastrar, depois digito 1 novamente para fazer apenas 1 cadastro. Quando volta pro menu eu escolho 2 para consultar e digito o CPF. Já fiz um teste no case 2 apenas para imprimir o user[0].CPF e aparece lixo de memoria.

Comment: Sim. Aí preencho os dados normal.

Comment: Então você digita `1\n1\n1\nNome\nm\n1234\n\n1.7\n80.4\n`?

Comment: Sim. Quando vou consultar no case 2 por esse CPF que foi inserido, aparece outro número.

Comment: Dado altura `1.5` e peso `22.5`, você obtém sempre valores distintos? Nunca `10.0`?

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta. O problema estou encontrando é na segunda opção do menu. Depois que faço o cadastro e vou consultar, os valores cadastrados são perdidos.

Comment: Estou fazendo uma edição na sua pergunta para acrescentar a sua operação, de modo que fique viável alguém tentar reproduzir. Para isso, preciso saber se, para uma pessoa de CPF `1234`, altura `1,5` e peso `22.5`, o que sai impresso quando eu a consulto é `10.0` ou sai impresso valores aleatórios?

Comment: Fiz a edição, poderia verificar se o que eu pus é consistente com o que você realmente está fazendo? Escrevi isso baseado em suas respostas aos comentários

Comment: Isso mesmo. Mas no case 2 não dá o resultado certo do IMC porque o valor de user[i].CPF está diferente do que foi inserido.

Comment: Eu fiz um teste deixando o código do case 2 apenas para exibir o CPF que foi cadastrado e aparece um valor aleatório.

Comment: Utilize a função malloc de <stdlib.h> para alocar a memória necessária para seu array de estruturas user.

Comment: Se você puder colocar o como você fez o teste (a modelo do que eu pus como edição), seria mais informação para a pergunta

Comment: @Anonimo, neste caso não é necessário, ele está usando alocação automática para tal efeito, mas só não pode se arrepender da contagem de cadastros

Comment: Lembre-se de que o valor da variável contUser não é conhecido em tempo de compilação. A maneira correta de se fazer alocação dinâmica é utilizar as funções apropriadas para isso.

Comment: @Anonimo, vide https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/215832/64969; alocação automática

Comment: @Nivaldo, percebi que você usar `typedef struct Cadastro {...};`, sendo que na minha lembrança, misturar declaração de estrutura com `typedef` segue o formato `typedef struct _cadastro {...} Cadastro;`, com o nome do novo tipo definido no fim. Isso em C puro, não C++. Você está usando qual linguagem? Talvez essa definição do jeito que está possa confundir o compilador

Comment: Estou salvando como cpp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O principal problema é a definição do vetor dentro do do-while. Isto faz com que o vetor seja inicializado toda vez que a repetição ocorre.

**Opção 1:**

```
main(){
    int opcao, contUser = 0;
    do{
        Menu();
        scanf("%i", &opcao);
        system("cls");
        if(opcao == 1){
        printf("Quantos cadastros deseja realizar? ");
        scanf("%i", &contUser);
        Cadastro user[contUser];
        system("cls");
        fflush(stdin);
        }
```

**Opção 2:**

```
main(){
    int opcao, contUser = 0;
    printf("Quantos cadastros deseja realizar? ");
    scanf("%i", &contUser);
    Cadastro user[contUser];
    do{
        Menu();
        scanf("%i", &opcao);
        system("cls");
        fflush(stdin);
        }
```

Comment: Exato. Era esse o problema.

Comment: Fico feliz em poder ajudar. Abraço